# Does rational come from ratio or ratio come from rational?

Tags: etymology, mathematics

Going through law school we often used the Latin phrase *[ratio decidendi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_decidendi)*, meaning the *reasoning of a decision*. In this context we took the latin word ***ratio*** to mean *thinking process*.

Recently I [saw an author make this observation](https://twitter.com/standaloneSA/status/549886972924530688):

> Whoa.  Term "Rational" number comes from ratio, since all rational numbers are the result of a ratio. How did I never learn that in school?

The author's argument seems to be that the Latin word *ratio* has the same meaning as the English word *ratio,* and then that mathematical reasoning preceded philosophical reasoning, leading to the word *rational* having a mathematical origin. I believe this is based on an incorrect assumption.

Now I'm inclined to think that the term *rational number* has a slightly different origin.

My question is: **Does rational come from ratio, or ratio come from rational?**

Comment: Why does the word *"rational"* in the sense of *"rational number"* need to have exactly the same etymology as the word *"rational"* in the sense of *"according to reason"*? Couldn't they have arisen from different senses of the Latin word *"ratio"*?

Comment: According to the [Mathematics Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/65568/1627), “rational” meaning a mathematical ratio and meaning ‘according to reason’ indeed have different etymologies, as Peter Shor suggests.

Comment: Actually, it says that _ratio_ comes from _rational_ (or more properly from the Latin word _ratio_ meaning '(something) rational; reason', since it was a legal term. Translating Euclid into Latin, the word the Greeks used for mathematical ratio (_logos_) got assigned to Latin _ratio_. In the 15th or 16th century; but the 'rational' part was much older and continued its own way in Latin, being stamped on the cannon of Louis XIV: ULTIMA RATIO REGUM 'the final argument of kings'.

Comment: The word *ratio* is the Latin noun corresponding to the adjective *rata* as in *pro rata* (meaning *in proportion,* i.e., *according to the proper ratio*; *rata* is also the source, via French, of the word *rate*). So the English mathematical meaning is not too distant from Latin. So both *rational number* and *rational thought* came from different meanings of the word *ratio* in Latin.

Comment: Come on lads, you know better than to answer in comments.

Comment: @Tim: well ... looking at the OED and doing a little online research shows that my comments were incorrect (a good reason for not making them an answer).

Comment: Note that it is often irrational to attempt to ascribe some sort of rationalization of how two English words are related.

Comment: @HotLicks: But inscribing some sort of irrationalization there is rational. (It might also be irrational.) ;-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The mathematical meaning of *ratio* comes from the mathematical meaning of *rational*, which in turn comes from the mathematical meaning of *irrational*.

The OED says that we get the word *irrational* from the Latin word *irrationalis*, which was used in Latin for both the mathematical and the non-mathematical sense of *irrational*. It appears that the mathematical senses of both *ratio* and *rational* are backformations from *irrational*.

Euclid called irrational numbers ἄλογος (*alogos*). Since the word *logos* in Greek means either *word* or *reason*, this would have meant either *unsayable numbers* or *unreasonable numbers*. I expect the name originally was intended to mean *unsayable numbers*; the ancient Greeks used rationals to identify numbers, so an irrational number would have been a number without a name. Furthermore, the word for the mathematical sense of *irrational* in modern Greek is άρρητος (arretos), which also means *unsayable*.

Anyway, the word ἄλογος was translated into Latin as *irrationalis*, and according to the OED, the mathematical sense of *irrational* is first attested in English in 1551, and the mathematical sense of *rational* in 1570. The mathematical sense of *ratio* is first attested in English in 1660, so it seems that the mathematical meaning of *ratio* was a backformation from *rational*. The word *ratio* means both *reason* and *calculation* in Latin, but I haven't found any evidence it was used to mean *ratio*, i.e., one quantity divided by another. One of the meanings of the related adjective *rata*, as in *pro rata*, does seem to have been *in ratio*, so the choice of *ratio* to mean this was not too unreasonable.

The backformation from *rational* to *ratio* presumably happened in English, because the French word *ratio* (same meaning as in English) was borrowed from English and not Latin ([see this link](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ratio) to *le trésor de la langue française informatisé*).

The backformation from *irrationalis* to *rationalis* happened in Latin.

Answer (score 2):

I read in a philosophy book (citation not kept) that the connection between ratio and rationality comes through Euclid. That for centuries, Euclidean geometry was held as the paradigm for reasoning, so much so that Descartes modelled his Cartesian method (an early milestone in the philosophy of science) on Euclidean geometry. So much so that when consistent non-Euclidean geometries were formulated in the 19th century, a moral and intellectual tremor shook Europe.

Euclid's method was to proceed by ratios. Euclid's arguments often take the form of if A:B as C:D. Two examples:

Proposition VI.1 asserts:
• Suppose a and b to be two line segments, and suppose that we erect on each a rectangle of the same height h. Then the **ratio** of the areas A and B of these rectangles is that same as the **ratio** of the lengths of the segments a and b.

Proposition VI.4 asserts:
• Suppose that two triangles hve the same angles. Then the **ratios** of corresponding sides are equal.

Both of these examples are from this document, "Euclid's Theory of Ratios."
http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/courses/m446-03/ratios.pdf

Euclid's method of reasoning came to be called "to proceed by the method of ratios."

Hence, ratio as the proportion of one number compared to another.
Hence too, ratio as rationality.

Comment: Do you mean “consistent ***non-*** Euclidean geometries”?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer if necessary.

Comment: Indeed I did. Duly edited.

Answer (score 1):

From the perspective of mathematics, at first we believed everything can be *compared*. Thus we got the *ratio*. And the number to represent such comparion is called *rational*. Then math crisis arose and we continued to discover more and more types of numbers that cannot be reprsented as ratio. So we collectively call them *irrational*, which merely means they are *not rational*. It's just a way of classification. Please avoid the overtune of the word in daily conversation.

With rational and irrational, we got the *real number*, which is closed under arithmetic and limit process. We call it *continuum*.

But unfortunately/interestingly, there are still more types of numbers to go...

### ADD 1 - 5:56 PM 7/11/2023

What I said above can be found in the book [Number: The Language of Science](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0452288118). Unfortunately, I don't remember the exact locations to cite.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).